# Cannot get line to draw on log scale y-axis, but can on linear

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to draw a simple line chart in D3.  I am able to draw the data line with a linear scale on the Y-axis (ignore the fact that there are no ticks):

[image]

Here is the code and a relevant [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VHd4r/5/) for this:

```
var margin = { top: 10, right: 245, bottom: 30, left: 100 },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Set the X and Y scale (e.g., linear vs. log) and the domains
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([-95,-74]).range([0, width]);

// ******* CHANGE linear() to log() *************************** //
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0.000010,1]).range([height, 0]);


// Set the locations of the axis (e.g., bottom and left)
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(0, ".1");;

// Set up some lines and related colors
var color = d3.scale.category10();
var line = d3.svg.line().x(function (d) { return x(d.power); }).y(function (d) { return y(d.ber); });

// Set the graph to be drawn in the respective div (grapharea), and set dimensions
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Append the X and Y axis to the actual SVG graph
svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(yAxis);
svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis);

// Parse the JSON data response
var jsonString = '[{"power":-91.0,"ber":0.0},{"power":-92.0,"ber":0.0},{"power":-93.0,"ber":1E-07},{"power":-94.0,"ber":6.5E-06},{"power":-95.0,"ber":0.000147}]';
var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonString);

jsonData.forEach(function (d) {
    d.ber = d.ber;
    d.power = d.power;
});

// Set the data properly
x.domain(d3.extent(jsonData, function(d) { return d.power; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(jsonData, function(d) { return d.ber; }));

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis)
.append("text")
.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
.attr("y", 6)
.attr("dy", ".71em")
.style("text-anchor", "end")
.text("BER");

svg.append("path")
.datum(jsonData)
.attr("class", "line")
.attr("d", line);
```

If all I change is linear() to log() on the variable `y`, then I get a resulting log scale graph but my data line no longer shows up ([relevant JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vh6J/1/)):

[image]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong for the data line to not show up on the log scale graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have zeros in your data. The log of zero is not defined. You'll need to use a different type of scale.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding something.  But my data point is 0 and I would want it to be plotted on the y-axis at 0, I do not want d3 or my script to calculate log(0) and plot that.  Where in my script would try to calculate log(0)?

Comment: But you are completely right in that if I remove the data points with 0, it plots a data line. I'm not sure how to solve this.

Comment: In a log scale, the log of all values that you pass in will be taken.